# How should I include csv data in a python put request using aiohttp

Tags: python, csv, salesforce, aiohttp

I'm trying to use the salesforce bulk api 2.0 to upsert some data, and they only accept csv data. In [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_bulk_v2.meta/api_bulk_v2/walkthrough_upsert.htm), for step 2, they say create the csv file. Then in step 4, I need to upload the csv data. I have code that doesn't throw any errors, but the record is not processed, which makes me think I am doing something wrong.
So I have the following as my csv_string:

```
csv_string = "Id, Name__c\n,\"Doe, John\""
```

Here is how I am currently sending the data

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/csv', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
data = {'file': csv_string}
async with self.session.put(upload_url, data = data, headers = headers) as response:
    r = await response.text()
    print(r)
```

According to the documentation, I am supposed to get " response that includes the job ID, with a job state of Open." but =it just prints an empty line.

Then when I do step 16: Check the job status and results, it successfully returns JobComplete and response.text() returns the following: `"sf__Id","sf__Created",file=Id%2C+Name__c%0A%2C+%22Doe%2C+John%22` which is basically a url encoded version of my csv_string. There is no change to the data in salesforce, so the upsert fails. The fact that an empty line is printed out makes me believe that I am not passing the csv in correctly.

I've tried using aiohttp's FormData, but that changes the data type to multi-part encoded which is not accepted. I've also tried passing `data = csv_string` which makes salesforce return an error. I was thinking maybe I need to pass it in as binary data, for example, when you open a file using `open("file_name", "rb")`, but I don't know how to convert this existing string to binary data. Can someone give an example of how to pass csv data in a request using aiohttp? Or maybe tell me how to convert this string to binary data to I can try passing it in this way?

Comment: The same doc you're citing tells you that upserts require an external ID column. You have an `Id` column with no value and it's not clear if `Name__c` is your external ID. Line ending might be another issue. Try debugging this whole sequence in Workbench (also mentioned in the doc), then port to python.

Comment: I was successfully able to upload it using workbench. When creating the job, I pass in the "externalIdFieldName" as "Id", and the lineEnding as "CRLF". The way the upsert works is that if the externalIdFieldName is blank, it will insert the object, and if it matches, it will update the object. So I don't think there is anything wrong with my data, I think it is just uploading the csv that is an issue.

Comment: CRLF is `\r\n`, you have `\n`

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @identigral. This was one of the issues.

One major thing that helped me debug was going to setup->bulk data load jobs. If you click on a specific job, and hover over the "state message", it will give you the reason why a job failed. Although salesforce has an api for getting the failed job record [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_bulk_v2.meta/api_bulk_v2/get_job_failed_results.htm), which supposedly is supposed to return an error message, it did not work, which is why I felt kind of stuck, and led me to believe I wasn't passing in the csv correctly.

So I had a few errors:

1. Like identigral pointed out, I used "CLRF" as the line ending because I thought I was on windows, but since I type out the string myself in the code, I had to use "LF". I believe if I read in a csv file that I create using Excel, I would probably have to use "CLRF", although I haven't tested it yet.
2. Salesforce doesn't like the space in front of "Name__c", so although I had a field with that name on my object, it said "field Name__c" not found.
3. The documentation I linked said that after uploading the csv, "You should get a response that includes the job ID still in the Open state." However, that is not the case. The PUT request to upload the csv will have an empty request body and only return status 201 if the request was successful. This is found here: [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_bulk_v2.meta/api_bulk_v2/upload_job_data.htm)

I realized this was the correct way as in this [documentation](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html), it gives an example of passing in data of type `text/plain` by doing `data='Привет, Мир!'`, so I figured text/csv should be the same.

So the final code to send the csv that ended up working is as follows: (self.session is an instance of aiohttp.ClientSession() and I had already included the bearer token in the default headers when initializing the session):

```
csv_string = "Id,Name__c\n,\"Doe,John\""
headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/csv', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
async with self.session.put(upload_url, data = csv_string, headers = headers) as response:
    assert response.status == 201 #data was successfully received.
```

The following was how I defined my when creating the job (replace MyObject__c with the API name of the object from salesforce):

```
body = {'object': 'MyObject__c', 
        'contentType': 'CSV', 
        'operation': 'upsert', 
        "lineEnding": "LF",
        "externalIdFieldName": "Id" }
```